# ios 10 Firebase Push Notification delegate method not called in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been struggling with this problem for days and I have looked at every post about this and nothing works.

I am using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). FCM talks directly to the app when in foreground, but it will use APNS when the app is in background.

I am trying to call a method everytime the app got notification by calling the method in the push notification's delegate function

I have these 2 delegate functions:
`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`

and

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)`

which does not get called in background, according to apple documentation.

I also have this function which I believe should get called in the background but it does not.
`func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

I have all of these functions in ViewController

In background mode, I get banner notifications, but none of the delegate is called. Is there any way to make any of them work in the background, if not what should I do?
In addition I also get this error : `<FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2` in the log everytime I send a payload while the app is in the background.

Here is the payload that I send using postmate:

`{
    "priority":"high",
    "notification":{
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": "1",
        "title":"mytitle",
        "body":"mybody",
        "message":"Hello"
    },
   "content_available":true,
   "to" : "/topics/myTopic"
}`

I already turned on push notification in capabilities and checked push notification in background modes under capabilities.

I use Xcode 8 and have been testing on iphone 6 iOS 10.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be 1 delegate for a protocol.

In this case, I made APPDelegate and ViewController conform to UIApplicationDelegate. And only delegate functions in APPDelegate got called. That's why the one in ViewController is not called.

The solution would be just put `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in the AppDelegate.